# Installation of node-inspector?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, node-inspector

```
node-gyp-rebuild-2-builderror-log
```

this error is coming continuously even after trying

```
npm install node-gyp -g
```

how to solve this and install node-inspector properly.

[image]

Comment: Please report an issue at github: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/new